# Generating a WSDL using Python and SOAPpy

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soappy, zsi

First of all, I will admit I am a novice to web services, although I'm familiar with HTML and basic web stuff.  I created a quick-and-dirty web service using Python that calls a stored procedure in a MySQL database, that simply returns a BIGINT value.  I want to return this value in the web service, and I want to generate a WSDL that I can give our web developers. I might add that the stored procedure only returns one value.

Here's some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import SOAPpy
import MySQLdb

def getNEXTVAL():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "CALL my_stored_procedure()" )  # Returns a number
    result=cursor.fetchall()

    for record in result:
        return record[0]

db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="myuser", passwd="********", db="testing")
server = SOAPpy.SOAPServer(("10.1.22.29", 8080))
server.registerFunction(getNEXTVAL)
server.serve_forever()
```

I want to generate a WSDL that I can give to the web folks, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have SOAPpy just generate one for me.  Is this possible?

Comment: This user's attempt is the best I've seen so far of someone generating WSDL for use with their SOAPServer:
http://osdir.com/ml/python.pywebsvcs.general/2006-07/msg00015.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I tried to write Python web service last year, I ended up using [ZSI-2.0](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/) (which is something like heir of SOAPpy) and a [paper available on its web](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/holger.pdf).

Basically I wrote my WSDL file by hand and then used ZSI stuff to generate stubs for my client and server code. I wouldn't describe the experience as pleasant, but the application did work.

Comment: I followed your advice and switched to ZSI instead of SOAPpy, and by using the paper and the other examples I *ALMOST* have it working now.  Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to implement my SOAP server using ZSI, but I encountered some problems. Can you take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996528/wsdl2dispatch-raises-exception-while-generating-server-file) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005474/how-to-force-zsi-to-accept-application-soapxml)?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to generate a WSDL that I can give to the web folks, ....

You can try [soaplib](http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/). It has on-demand WSDL generation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the question few days ago. Now I can invoke the server successfully. A demo is provided:

```
def test_soappy():
    """test for SOAPpy.SOAPServer
    """
    #okay
    # it's good for SOAPpy.SOAPServer.
    # in a method,it can have morn than 2 ws server.
    server = SOAPProxy("http://localhost:8081/")
    print server.sum(1,2)
    print server.div(10,2)
```