# How to send raw XML in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to send raw xml to a service in Python. I have a the address of the service and my question is how would I wrap XML in python and send it to the service. The address is in the format below.

```
192.1100.2.2:54239
```

And say the XML is:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><header/><body><code><body/>
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415192/best-way-to-create-a-simple-python-web-service

Comment: (That's neither a valid IP address nor well-formed XML.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
import socket
import time

command = '<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><header/><body><code><body/>'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.1100.2.2", 54239))

s.send(command)

time.sleep(2)
resp = s.recv(3000)

print resp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pydoc socket
```

... should get you started.

PS.  Your example IP address looks a bit strange (1100 is greater than 255), but maybe that's just so nobody tries to use it ...

Comment: IP address is indeed invalid.