# can python (version 2.6 ) create web services on the windows(32)?

Tags: python, service

can python (version 2.6 ) create web services on the windows(32)? i hava a program that need python create a web service project.python 2.6 linked to mysql.

In China , less men develop it,so i can't find modules for web services!!
if not,Linux may be the next step.

Comment: you mean like SimpleHTTPServer?

Comment: Webservice means? XMLRPC? HTTP? SOAP? be specific!

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks. There's a ton of web frameworks for Python that will work on any platform. I'm not sure *exactly* what you mean by "web service", but I promise you that you'll find something that meets your needs on that list.

Comment: Someone care to tell me why the downmod? Can't get much more specific than a list of the options.

Comment: @Diavd and there's a list of libraries to create web services there.

Comment: What *do* you mean when you say **web services**? I would have posted the same answer myself...

Comment: unless you specific the kind of webservices you are interested in, such an answer is too broad..it's like "yes, buy a car when you want to travel for a long distance".

Comment: @Diavd if this answers your question, you can give me an upvote and accept it! @RestRisiko apparently the OP was satisfied.

Comment: @Rafe Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service. Basically it is about exposing an API to interact with the website

Comment: @Oscar I know what a web service is, I just don't know if he want REST, SOAP, etc.

Comment: Chinese net is limited! i can't regist it!

Comment: @Diavd you can still upvote me, I believe. I don't think you have to be registered to give votes on your own questions. If it's not possible, it's not possible, I guess

Comment: If you don't know what he want then don't give an unspecific unrelated hint.

Comment: @RestRisiko I have a basic idea, but there was no specificity in the question, so the answer can't be particularly specific.

Comment: Ok , i try my best.O(∩_∩)O！ this is my first time coming here!

Comment: @Rafe I voted up your answer, so you're not negative anymore (even if you already have `10.7k` points :D)

Comment: sorry ,Rafe,i try it .when i chick flag,i tell me to login.Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can start by taking a look at:

[Best way to create a simple python web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415192/best-way-to-create-a-simple-python-web-service)
[Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/)

[WebServices - PythonInfo Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices)
[Dive Into Python: SOAP Web Services](http://diveintopython.net/soap_web_services/)
[Python Web Services](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: everyone here so nice and great, i feel that IT is strong in foreign!! and i learn JAVA for 2 years ,Spring ,hibernate ands struts2。In China ,lots of companys develop with them!!

Comment: @Diavd just to ask... why should we care, in this context, about that you've learned Java, Hibernate, Spring,... when you're asking a question about Web services in Python?

Comment: I just introduce something.people in china always learn the three! i believe that 1% students will learn it!but ,i feel that python and web services learned by lots of students and men,right?