# Access folder on Web Server using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, networking, web-applications

I am trying to find ways, by which a user can open a folder on web-server on button click in a web application, based on windows authentication and no impersonation.

Two methods, that i have came across are :

- Using href link, it works, but only in IE.

  `<a href="\\test\c$\xyz">Open</a> "`
- Using C#, It doesn't seem to work, i gave permissions to Application Pool and Users to access the folder, but was getting access denied.

  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\test\c$\xyz");`

Comment: <"a href="\test\tr2\xyz">Open<"/a>"
are you sure it will open folder on web-server?

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I deliberately added those (""), so that the string could appear, and not the html element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with "accessing to administrative shares isn't a good idea", if your users attempts to access to it as normal user (i.e. probably not logged/verified by a domain controller) will surely fails.

Assuming you want to access to a granted share you should link using **file:** as URI scheme.

Local folder:

`<a href="file:///D:/Downloads/">click me</a>`

Remote folder:

`<a href="file://///test/sharedfolder/">click me</a>`

here works both with IE and FF.

Read this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx

Taken from:
[How to open a windows folder when clicking on some link on a HTML page using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806853/how-to-open-a-windows-folder-when-clicking-on-some-link-on-a-html-page-using-pyt)