# How to avoid automatic appended file extensions to directory links when converting to pdf using pandoc?

Tags: pdf, markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I'm writing company internal documentation in R markdown and compiling using knitr in Rstudio.  I'm trying to add a link pointing to a directory as follows:

```
[testdir](file:////c:/test/)
```

(this is following the convention described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806853/how-to-open-a-windows-folder-when-clicking-on-some-link-on-a-html-page-using-pyt))

When I compile it to html, I get the following link.

```
<a href="file:////c:/test/">testdir</a>
```

and it works as expected in Internet explorer.  However, when I try to convert to pdf straight from RStudio, an unwanted pdf extension is appended to the link.  I tried dissecting the problem and it seems this change is happening within pandoc.  Here are the details.

When I convert it to latex using pandoc,

```
>pandoc -f markdown -t latex testing.md -o test.tex
```

the link in the latex output file looks as follows:

```
\href{file:///c:/test/}{testdir}
```

Everything good so far.  However, when I convert the latex output to pdf with pandoc,

```
>pandoc -f latex -t latex -o test.pdf test.tex
```

a .pdf extension is appended to the link.  Here is a copy/paste of the pdf link output:

```
/c:/test/.pdf
```

is there a way to avoid this unwanted appended extension?

Perhaps I'm asking too much of pandoc, but I thought it might be worth asking since RStudio is becoming such a useful IDE to write my dynamic documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the .tex file pandoc generates is fine. So the problem is actually with LaTeX, specifically with the `hyperref` package which is used in [pandoc's LaTeX template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates).

The problem with two possible solutions was [described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/hyperref-how-to-open-a-directory-view-with-href). To prevent hyperref from being smart and adding a file extensions, try:

```
[testdir](file:///c:/test/.)
```

Or use ConTeXt instead of LaTeX:

```
$ pandoc -t context -s testing.md -o test.tex && context test.tex
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll report when I try it. I've been distracted by more pressing projects. And of course, documentation took the back seat.

Comment: I was able to test this today and it worked like a charm.  Thanks @mb21 !