# Posting GCM registration ID from client app to a Django model

Tags: django, post, django-models, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple Django Model to save registration id and IMEI of users using my Android app:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    registration_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    imei_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

It has an accompanying view:

```
class DeviceCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Device
    form_class = DeviceForm
```

The view is referred to quite simply in urls.py like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', DeviceCreateView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

And there's a corresponding forms.py which has:

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ("registration_id", "imei_id")
```

Lastly, this is the template to go with all that:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This gives me a neat little web service to manually input the regis_id and the IMEI of the device, and store it in the database. 
But what I instead want is a way to **directly post the regis_id and the IMEI from the client app to my Django model**, instead of doing it manually. The client end isn't my task, I just have to do the server end. How do I change my web service such that it can "receive" the relevant value(s) from the client? This might be straightforward, but being a newbie, I'm struggling with figuring this out. Can anyone give me a simple example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered, you need a url where your android app can send data (i.e. in the form of an xml and the url can directly store the data in your DB)
If that is correct then I believe the keyword you're looking for is '[wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/)'.

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415192/best-way-to-create-a-simple-python-web-service) can help out in understanding and writing a basic webservice.