# how to create a wsdl file for using soap server in python

Tags: python, soap, python-2.7, wsdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a WSDL using Python and SOAPpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273002/generating-a-wsdl-using-python-and-soappy)

How to create a simple Wsdl file for using the soap server in python and then later use it for soap ui for testing web services. Just a simple example.

Comment: How can one do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/arskom/spyne
have a look at that. Nice library, has good documentation and is able to generate wsdl for a soap-service